How to authenticate with JWT and receive a user object (API in different project)?
I have two Symfony 7.1 projects - one provides an API (named "core" - uses API Platform v4 and JWT Lexik Bundle), the other is a web based front-end to access the data (named "dashboard"). Users login to the dashboard, which asks the core for a Json Web Token (JWT) via a HTTP request.
I understood that the JWT Lexik Bundle was aimed at being on the project that provides the API (core, in my case). However, I'm struggling to understand if there's something I can have on the client side (dashboard, in my case) which helps to retrieve the JWT and convert it into a UserInterface object that contains the roles etc.
Is this something is possible with a Symfony project, or should I manually retrieve the roles via another API call? Would using the Lexik bundle on both sides help?
Edit:
I've made some progress by installing the Lexik bundle in both apps and changing /config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml as follows:
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'

    token_extractors:
        cookie:
            enabled: true
            name: 'jwt'
        authorization_header:
            enabled: false

When I then authenticate against my API manually and retrieve the JWT, I set this as a secure cookie. The Lexik bundle then is able to pick this cookie up because of the above config, and I can use the various Symfony functions to allow/deny access by role.
It seems that there may be a simpler way, but it's working OK for the moment.

JWTUserInterface should do this for you. When Lexik creates a token, it embeds the roles into the JWT payload. See here.

Thanks Alex - I'll try installing the Lexik bundle on the client project then and using the info from your link. Much appreciated

I've installed the bundle on my client side app ("dashboard"). I'm not sure if I'm misreading the documentation, but by installing the package and configuring the firewall, I'm not able to get a User object back. I can prove the JWT contains the necessary bits by decoding it. However, most examples seem to assume that you have the API and the thing accessing it within the same application, which I don't.  Does anyone have links to examples where the thing users are authenticating from is a different project?

I am using Lexik to authenticate from tokens created by Auth0, which has a slightly different payload structure than Lexik's own tokens, so I had to make a custom user class implementing JWTUserInterface, but your configuration should otherwise be pretty much the same.
Check the docs for database-less user provider. Something like this should work for you. In config/packages/security.yaml, tell Symfony to get its user information from Lexik:
security:
    # Register the JWT provider.
    providers:
        jwt:
            lexik_jwt: ~
    # Tell Symfony to use the JWT provider for this case.
    firewalls:
        main:
            jwt: ~
            provider: jwt
            stateless: true
    # Now your user object should have roles like normal.
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }


Thank you. That looks very similar to my config. Are you allowing users to login via a form in the app? I guess that may not be the case if you are using Auth0. I assume I need the normal LoginFormAuthenticator, POST to my API to get a JWT, the the Lexik bundle takes over and gives me a JWTUserInterface back that I can retrieve in the session?

I might be a bit confused about your app setup. You have users logging in, with userid and password, to the web app, for a persistent session with state? The front end site takes that user/pass, passes it to the backend API project, which validates it and (if successful) generates a JWT, which the front end should then use to access the API for the rest of the user's session? Is that correct?

Spot on! And ideally, the front-end app should see it as a "proper" user that I can use in the normal way against a firewall, and to run is_granted() checks for example. I've made some progress by install the Lexik bundle on the front-end, setting a cookie with the received JWT and then configuring the token_extractors: cookie: enabled: true  - this seems to work, but is a little convoluted. I've yet to find an example online of using two Symfony apps in this exact config - most demos seem to assume the API sits inside the same app as the front-end

Ah ok, I have misunderstood your original request. The JWTUser is for the case where the end-user themselves is presenting the token, which isn't what you're doing. You're using the remote API as your user authenticator, versus (for example) a local database lookup. I think you'll want to make a custom user class based on JWTUser -- if the session doesn't already exist, have it hit the remote API w/ the user/pass, the existing code in JWTUser will extract the roles (so your is_granted() works), and then store the token in the user session for future API hits.

I would not store the token in a cookie, the end user should not have access to it.

Thanks. The cookie method is working well enough for now, but it would be handy to find the part of the JWT Lexik bundle that actually does the bit that converts a JWT string into the JwtUser class - that way I could call it directly without setting the cookie.

To authenticate with JWT and fetch a user object from an API in another project, follow these steps:
Obtain the JWT: Log in through the API and receive the token after providing valid credentials.
Include the JWT: Send the token in the Authorization header as Bearer <your_token> when calling the user-related endpoint.
Verify the Token: The API validates the JWT to ensure it's legitimate and not expired.
Fetch the User Object: On successful verification, the API sends back the requested user object in the response.
This approach ensures secure data exchange while keeping your systems modular.
